# Ipfs extend pining time Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ipfs, temporal

I am using IPFS service for file storage. I have a few questions?

1. Files can be stored in a specific period through Pinning after
   the pining time ends files deleted or not?
2. I have a thousand
   files in IPFS How can I extend the pinning time of All Hashes
   instead of extending one by one through hash?

Comment: You probably want to use the support channels for the particular service you are using. These questions aren't related to IPFS in general, and are specific to the service provider you are using. The best option is to use whatever support channel the service provides

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) there is no API for expiring pins (`ipfs pin --help`) at the moment. It is up to you to implement pinning orchestration in the code of your app.

You can keep data around (protect it from being garbage collected) with:

- low level  [`ipfs.pin.*` API](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/PIN.md) for pinning and unpinning after some time
- [MFS](https://docs-beta.ipfs.io/concepts/file-systems/#mutable-file-system-mfs) – data stored in MFS is protected from GC (its  "implicitly pinned") so you can add / remove files to/from MFS to control what is kept around

Ad 2) You can create a DAG which includes all CIDs that you want to keep around and  pin the root CID recursively, or add it to MFS.